# Angular 7 : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, angular, http

I am stuck on this SQL error and I do not understand why:

**SQL Table**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `cinego` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `cinego`;

-- Listage de la structure de la table cinego. salle
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `salle` (
  `idSalle` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plan` blob,
  `nbPlace` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idCinema` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idTechno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idSalle`),
  KEY `ref_salle_cinema` (`idCinema`),
  KEY `ref_salle_techno` (`idTechno`),
  CONSTRAINT `ref_salle_cinema` FOREIGN KEY (`idCinema`) REFERENCES `cinema` (`idCinema`),
  CONSTRAINT `ref_salle_techno` FOREIGN KEY (`idTechno`) REFERENCES `technologie` (`idTechno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my table that is present in a DB Mysql.

**Typescript**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-room-add',
  templateUrl: './room-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./room-add.component.scss']
})
export class RoomAddComponent implements OnInit {
  cinema: Cinema = new Cinema();
  techno: Techno = new Techno();
  cinemas: Cinema[] = [];
  technos: Techno[] = [];
  addRoomForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    blueprint: new FormControl(''),
    placelenght: new FormControl(''),
    cinema: new FormControl(''),
    techno: new FormControl(''),
  });   
  constructor(
    private roomService: RoomService,
    private cinemaService: CinemaService
  ) { }   
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cinemaService.getAllCinemas().subscribe(data => {
      this.cinemas = data['content'];
      console.log(this.cinemas);
    });
    this.roomService.getAllTechnos().subscribe(data => {
      this.technos = data['content'];
      console.log(this.technos);
    });
  }    
  onAdd(): void {
    const room: Room = this.addRoomForm.value;
    this.roomService.createRoom(room).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    console.log(room);
  }    
}
```

This is my code behind my Angular component.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="room-add-form" [formGroup]="addRoomForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (submit)="onAdd()">
    <mat-form-field class="room-add-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Nom de la salle" formControlName="name">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="room-add-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Plan" formControlName="blueprint">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="room-add-full-width">
      <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Nombre de place" formControlName="placelenght">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Cinéma" formControlName="cinema">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let cinema of cinemas" [value]="cinema.id">
          {{cinema.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Technologie" formControlName="techno">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let techno of technos" [value]="techno.id">
          {{techno.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I already tried to change the events during an update / delete in the table, this didn't work.

On Postman, the post request is working fine on my API.

Angular version : 7.3.1

**EDIT**

I forgot to add the error message

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cinego`.`salle`, CONSTRAINT `ref_salle_cinema` FOREIGN KEY (`idCinema`) REFERENCES `cinema` (`id`))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, this side Angular, in my service that retrieves HTTP responses.

```
createRoom(item: Room): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<Room>(`${API_BASE_URL}/salle`, this.getFormUrlEncoded(item), {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    });
  }
```

I added a function that manually encode the results of the Form into FormUrlEncode.

```
getFormUrlEncoded(toConvert) {
    const formBody = [];
    // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
    for (const property in toConvert) {
      const encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
      const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(toConvert[property]);
      formBody.push(encodedKey + '=' + encodedValue);
    }
    return formBody.join('&');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the table *cinema* populated first before inserting records in the *salle* table? I can see that *cinema.idCinema* is a reference key id for *salle* table so trying to validate it. Based from the error, a new entry must be present first in the *cinema* table before inserting a record in the *salle* table.

Comment: Yes, the cinema table contains these same data with the correct associated id.